# TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'explain' method on a 'Collection'

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

When I am trying to call `explain()` in my python file it is giving an error:

```
'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'explain' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

`db.collection.explain().aggregate(pipeline=data_pipe)`

I want an explanation of my query with ExecutionTime, saveState, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explain() only works in mongodb terminal thats why when I am running explain() with mongodb query in python file it is giving error